# Actionscript 3 - get position of Cursor in TextArea?

Tags: actionscript-3, cursor, textarea, position, textfield

I am making something in Actionscript 3, where people can modify a piece of text, within a TextArea.
Now, it's easy to get the typed character, but using event.getChar.

But, I would also like to know where the character was typed: the (text)cursor position.
I've read about that it's easy to do with a TextField, however, I want to use a TextArea for a few reasons:

I've read about it being possible with a TextField, but I'm not sure how I would make that into an input field...

Also, the TextArea is recommended for multiline text.

If I could hack a TextField to behave like a TextArea, I'm fine with that.

So, my question:
**How can I get the position of the cursor in a TextArea?**

or

**How can I make a TextField behave like a TextArea?**

EDIT: I managed to make an input TextField, but the caretIndex returns xyz coordinates, pretty useless for text editing/comparing... Any suggestions on that?

Comment: Do you mean the mouse cursor (arrow), or the keyboard cursor (vertical blinking line)?

Answer (score 3):

you can see which letter was clicked in a textfield by doing the following:

```
var tf:TextField;
var clicked_on_index:int = tf.getCharIndexAtPoint(tf.mouseX, tf.mouseY);//find index of char clicked on in string
var clicked_on_char:String = tf.text.substr( clicked_on_index, 1 );//find char clicked on from textfield
```

or if you just want to know the position of the last character entered:

```
var tf:TextField;
tf.addEventListener(Event.CHANGE,function(event:Event):void{
    var newCharacterPosition:int=tf.caretIndex;
    var totalCharacters:int=tf.text.length;
});
```

Comment: How about the typed characters?
Because I want to sync the new characters between different users...
And sending the whole piece of text every time would be a bit ridiculous :S

Comment: this should work for input tf as well... altho I havent tried it

Comment: No, I meant I want to know the position of the newly typed characters in the textfield, not the x and y position, but the position in the piece of text... do you think that is possible?

Comment: so... if the user is typing "hello world" when they type "d" you want to know that its position 11?  I can write another answer if thats what you need

Comment: Yep, that is exactly what I mean. However, very hard I think. Especially because you can not appendText at a certain position? or can you?
At the moment I think I'm going to send the whole piece of text, compressed in a ByteArray. Unless, ofcourse, I get this to work.

Comment: updated the answer to show the new character position when someone types in the textfield.  you can add more text to a TF by getting the string out of the TF via textField.text and editing the string then setting it back to the textField